# When using Flutter package mysql1, my dates seem to drift by the amount of my time zone

Tags: flutter, dart, mariadb

I save my date as a local date, but when I read it back, it treats it as if it was a UTC date so it slips by several hours.

The dates are passed in as strings in the form '2020-03-05 09:05:23' as query parameters but when they are retrieved they might look like '2020-03-04 10:05:23' because I am 13 hours ahead of Greenwich.

Answer (score 0):

For MariaDB (or MySQL):

- Use `DATETIME` as a picture of the clock on the wall.
- Use `TIMESTAMP` to adjust to the system's timezone.
- Set the system's timezone according to where it lives in the world.

Comment: Thanks Rick, the problem is in the dartlang driver implementation. I've forked and patched the driver for my situation. I'll discuss the issue with Adam who owns the original implementation.